# Arreglo de objetos Java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una duda con respecto a los arreglos de objetos, en la imagen adjunta tengo la declaración del arreglo, luego cargo con el método set, pero a la hora de devolverme el arreglo cargado no me devuelve ningún valor, ya hice los constructores y las propiedades de cada atributo de la clase persona, y por medio del set asigne los valores que va a tener cada espacio del arreglo pero no se que hacer para que el arreglo me muestre los valores, exactamente los valores de una posición que yo indique mediante una validación.

Algún consejo de que debería corregir en mi código o cambiar.

```
 public Persona[] ConsultarSaldo(Persona[] arreglo){

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo[i] != null){
        Persona objtemporal = new Persona();
        objtemporal = arreglo[i];


            double SaldoActual = objtemporal.getSaldo();
            objtemporal.setSaldo(SaldoActual);
            arreglo[i] = objtemporal;

        }        
    }
        return arreglo;
```

Lo que necesito es pre cargar el arreglo y que cuando yo llame algún método me devuelva el valor guardado, pero no me lo esta devolviendo, en si el ejercicio es asignar desde el principio los valores de la clase persona a 10 clientes por medio de un arreglo, y eso es lo que intentaba hacer por medio del set, pero cuando por ejemplo pido saber cuanto tiene de saldo la persona en la cuenta me devuelve 0, como si no tuviera nada ,de igual manera con los demás atributos, obvio uso un método donde el get llama a dichos valores que se supones están cargados ya en el arreglo

Al solicitar el saldo no me esta devolviendo el saldo de ninguna de las 10 posiciones del array

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código en vez de una imagen?

Comment: De lo que se ve en el código eso trata ser java, pero no lo es java. Aquí hubiera que explicar desde cero.

Answer (score 2):

## Actualización

> Para obtener todos los saldos del array recibido de personas

```
public double[] saldos(Personas[] personas) {
    if (personas != null) {
        double[] saldos = new double[personas.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < personas.length; i+=1) {
            saldos[i] = personas[i].getSaldo();
        }
        return saldos;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Según he entendido, quieres realizar un método `set(arrayPersona, posicion, valoresPersona)` que modifique tu array de personas y después otro método que muestre todo el contenido de dicho array.

### Cambios a realizar

- Refactorizar clase Persona

  - Utilizar [patrón de diseño builder](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) (simple).
  - Incluir métodos de clase (estáticos) para realizar las funciones de añadir, cambiar, y mostrar recibiendo siempre el array de Personas al cual hacemos referencia.

> Código

```
public class Persona {

    // ESTÁTICOS

    public static boolean add(Persona[] personas, Persona persona) {
        for (int i = 0; i < personas.length; i++) {
            if (personas[i] == null) {
                personas[i] = persona;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void show(Persona[] personas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < personas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(personas);
        }
    }

    public static void set(Persona[] personas, int posicion, Persona persona) {
        if (personas != null && persona != null) {
            personas[posicion] = persona; // Estaría bien comprobar la posición
        }
    }

    // CAMPOS

    private String cuenta, identificacion, nombre;
    private int clave;
    private double saldo;
    private boolean bloqueado;

    // MÉTODOS


    public Persona() {
    }

    public String getCuenta() {
        return cuenta;
    }

    public Persona setCuenta(String cuenta) {
        this.cuenta = cuenta;
        return this;
    }

    public String getIdentificacion() {
        return identificacion;
    }

    public Persona setIdentificacion(String identificacion) {
        this.identificacion = identificacion;
        return this;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public Persona setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        return this;
    }

    public int getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public Persona setClave(int clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
        return this;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public Persona setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isBloqueado() {
        return bloqueado;
    }

    public Persona setBloqueado(boolean bloqueado) {
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona{" +
                "cuenta='" + cuenta + '\'' +
                ", identificacion='" + identificacion + '\'' +
                ", nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
                ", clave=" + clave +
                ", saldo=" + saldo +
                ", bloqueado=" + bloqueado +
                '}';
    }
}

public class MainPersonas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persona[] personas = new Persona[10];

        Persona.add(personas, new Persona()
                .setCuenta("1")
                .setIdentificacion("1-1371-0735")
                .setNombre("Angelo")
                .setClave(1234)
                .setSaldo(25000.00)
                .setBloqueado(false)
        );

        Persona.set(personas, 0, new Persona()
                .setCuenta("2")
                .setIdentificacion("1-1111-1111")
                .setNombre("Carlos")
                .setClave(1111)
                .setSaldo(1000.00)
                .setBloqueado(false)
        );

        Persona.show(personas);

    }
}
```

Comment: no exactamente, lo que necesito es pre cargar el arreglo y que cuando yo llame algún método me devuelva el valor guardado, pero no me lo esta devolviendo, en si el ejercicio es asignar desde el principio los valores de la clase persona a 10 clientes por medio de un arreglo, y eso es lo que intentaba hacer por medio del set, pero cuando por ejemplo pido saber cuanto tiene de saldo la persona en la cuenta me devuelve 0, como si no tuviera nada ,de igual manera con los demás atributos, obvio uso un método donde el get llama a dichos valores que se supones están cargados ya en el arreglo

Comment: @AngeloCastro he actualizado la respuesta según lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias,  ya corregí con los métodos que me sugeriste, aun así no logro que el arreglo muestre los valores.

Comment: ¿Qué arreglo, el de saldos, o el de personas? ¿Te refieres a cuando obtienes los saldos que quieres mostrarlos?

Comment: cuando solicito el mostrar el saldo por medio de un método, no me devuelve el valor guardado en saldo, a eso me refiero, hice el arreglo, lo cargué y luego en el método que realiza la consulta de saldo al traer el valor guardado en la variable Saldo por medio del get no me lo trae me muestra 0.

Comment: En cuanto a que arreglo, trabajo todo desde el mismo ya que es un arreglo de objetos.